# Page anchors in short amounts of text

Tags: html, anchor

My client REALLY wants to link sub pages to anchors on certain web pages. Easy right? Well not when the page is so short, the anchors don't exactly "anchor" directly to the heading it's assigned to. Example is at http://axiomwest.com/about-us/. If you hover over the ABOUT US nav item at the top of the page and choose one of the dropdowns, her complaint is that they do not anchor to the proper heading. I tried explaining to her that anchors really work best on long pages of content, not for this particular site (this is exactly how she wanted it, against all of my warnings and professional advice). Is there any workaround here? Suggestions? Should I fire her?

Comment: The problem is not that the page is short, the problem is that there is a fixed position element positioned across the top of the page. (It is a horrible design that eats (with **no** exaggeration) *more then half my browser window*. That doubles the amount of scrolling I have to do to read the page. The solution is to let the header scroll with the page.

Comment: I agree David, but see my comment below @Wesley.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing personal, but I really don't like the way this site is laid out with the static header, it makes the content area, the area a user cares about most, way too small. This is also contributing to your problem.

2 things I would do:

- Ditch the fixed header and move to a more conventional design where the content is visible when you scroll
- Add a generous amount of bottom padding to the content area to avoid short pages. This will fix the anchor problem you're having.

If it makes you feel any better, I had to make a Flying Santa Claus shoot randomly across the screen for a client last year while country music played in the background. Wish I was kidding.

Seriously though, that header takes up the entire page unless my browser is maximized. I literally can't see any content at all. I imagine that a lot of common folk with 12 IE toolbars won't be able to see any content either. You should just make an alternate version and *ask the client* which one they like best. If they are really pushing the bad design after you've explained the reasons not to use it, just do what you have to do to get the job over and let them come back to you next month when they get complaints. It will even make you look better in a "Told you so" kind of way.

Comment: I totally agree with the layout comment Wesley. I totally lost all creative control with this project and honestly had one of the most challenging and frustrating clients in my 10 year career. I dread placing this in my company's portfolio. I cannot however change the mind of this particular client and mainly want it out of my hands and have them somewhat happy. It's tough to deal with a client that shoots hidden insults your way after giving them what they asked for and spending hours beyond the proposal to make it that way.

Comment: Well, one thing: Not every piece of work has to go in your portfolio. Another: Making the client happy is the top priority, but I understand the challenge of trying to balance it with best practices and having what you consider to be a good product. Ignore the insults and just play nice - you catch more flies with honey. Explain to her in a non-condescending manner the problems with any "bad" requests. Use your professional experience and give real examples. Usually they will bend to your will if you make it feel like it was *their* decision.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing you can do about it apart from appending dummy content to the DOM to make the page taller... and even then it's entirely dependent upon the client's resolution and viewport size.

Silly client is silly imo.

You might consider implementing some type of visual cue, i.e. highlight-pulse, on the anchor when it's activated.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I can see addressing their desire

1. Pad out the footer of the page so their is enough space after the body of the text to scroll the anchored text to the top of the page when clicked.
2. Use jquery highlight to highlight the section when navigated.